# Cant find proper screen layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm working on an android app, and almost done, the only problem is screen layouting, I have a samsung ace and samsung s4. According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), they are both on normal screen, and s4 is categorized on both normal and large.

I don't know what to do, I have layout-normal that works for my samsung ace but not for s4.

I'd tried layout-sw600dp for s4 but still don't work, if you have a better idea please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **layout-large** for your s4.

if that doesn't work you can handle checking and reacting to the s4 programmatically.

Comment: i already tried layout large, but what do you mean by "checking and reacting to the s4 programmatically".

Comment: @user2851687 you would check for what device is currently running your activity and change the layouting and other things programatically.